# object vs instance vs reference in java

Tags: java

Can anyone explain what is the difference between object vs instance vs reference, with a good example?

I'm confused about this part:

1. `( classA a;

    a = new classA();  )`
2. `( classA a;

    a = new classB();  )`
3. `( classA a;

    classB a = new classB();  )`

Comment: why the random tags?

Comment: Reference points to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 4):

`classA a` is a reference variable.

`new classA();` created Object / Instance

`a = new classB()` is assign object reference to variable

Comment: Then what is classA a; classB a = new classB();

Comment: Its actually 2 statement - ``classA a; `` is a statement just declared reference  variable without assignment.  and ``classB a = new classB();`` is a statement with assigment

Answer (score 0):

ClassA a is reference

a = new ClassA() a object os asign reference  to variable

2
a = new classB() is pass the reference of classB

3
Here classA is override becauseeyou set same same name of reference